# Product field in WordPress form changes when adding a new field?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am **very** new to WordPress and I am trying to edit a registration form by adding more fields. When I add a new text field, the product field no longer displays the product and price and just shows the default. I didn't make the website I just need to edit this, I am using the Gravity Forms plugin.

This is the form before editing:
[image]

And after adding a new field the product field ( in green writing) reverts to default values:

[image]

I can't figure out what makes it change so if you have come across this problem before or have any advice please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet there is some custom code at play here is that is dependent on the field ID. When you change the field, it has a new ID, and the custom code isn't being applied. I'd suggest doing a full theme/plugin conflict (start with your theme) to see where that custom code resides:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/testing-for-a-themeplugin-conflict/

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your help and sorry for the late reply. I have tried testing for conflicts following your suggestions, the form page displays a "Page cannot be found" message when a theme change is made so could this be a theme issue? I also tested for plug in conflicts- disabled all plugins and enabled them one at a time and there was no difference the problem was still apparent with no other plug ins active.

Comment: Try using Gravity Forms' preview mode.